# Does the following declaration result in a lexical analyzer error or not?

Tags: compiler-construction

```
nti a, b;
```

Now here I have replaced `int` with `nti`. Will it produce any lexical error or not?

Also, If I use

```
Int a, b;
```

is it a syntax error only or a lexical error ?

Comment: Why do you think `Int` and `nti` would behave differntly? Compilers are very simple: either you spell it `int` or you don't. `Int` is as close as `quusfgl_4531`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this depends on the language, but in most languages both `nti` and `Int` are valid identifiers and would thus be classified by the lexical analyzer as such. So there'd be no lexical error.

If the language further uses a C-style declaration syntax and allows user-defined types, both examples could also be syntactically valid. Only during semantic analysis would you get an error saying that no type named `nti` or `Int` is defined (unless, of course, it is, in which case the code is simply correct).

An exception to this are C and C++ themselves though, where defined types have to be kept track of at parse time and `foo bar;` does not correctly get parsed as a declaration unless `foo` has previously been declared as a type. In other C-derived languages however, this parses fine and behaves as described above.

So in summary: Depending on the language it may be a syntactical or semantic error. It is never a lexical error (unless we're talking about the extremely unusual case of a language without identifiers or where identifiers don't consist of letters).